# twitter4j error: The constructor TwitterObjectFactory(Configuration) is undefined: Here is the code:-

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

```
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class GetUserStatus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterObjectFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        UserStreamListener listener = new UserStreamListener() {
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("onStatus @" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                //System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            public void onDeletionNotice(long directMessageId, long userId) {
               // System.out.println("Got a direct message deletion notice id:" + directMessageId);
            }

            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
               // System.out.println("Got a track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }


            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
               // System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }


//            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
//               // System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
//            }


            public void onFriendList(long[] friendIds) {
                /*System.out.print("onFriendList");
                for (long friendId : friendIds) {
                    System.out.print(" " + friendId);
                }
                System.out.println();*/
            }

              public void onFavorite(User source, User target, Status favoritedStatus) {
               /* System.out.println("onFavorite source:@"
                        + source.getScreenName() + " target:@"
                        + target.getScreenName() + " @"
                        + favoritedStatus.getUser().getScreenName() + " - "
                        + favoritedStatus.getText());*/
            }


            public void onUnfavorite(User source, User target, Status unfavoritedStatus) {
               /*System.out.println("onUnFavorite source:@"
                                + source.getScreenName() + " target:@"
                                + target.getScreenName() + " @"
                                + unfavoritedStatus.getUser().getScreenName()
                                + " - " + unfavoritedStatus.getText());*/
            }


            public void onFollow(User source, User followedUser) {
                /*System.out.println("onFollow source:@"
                        + source.getScreenName() + " target:@"
                        + followedUser.getScreenName());*/
            }


            public void onDirectMessage(DirectMessage directMessage) {
               /* System.out.println("onDirectMessage text:"
                        + directMessage.getText());*/
            }


            public void onUserListMemberAddition(User addedMember, User listOwner, UserList list) {
                /*System.out.println("onUserListMemberAddition added member:@"
                        + addedMember.getScreenName()
                        + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserListMemberDeletion(User deletedMember, User listOwner, UserList list) {
               /* System.out.println("onUserListMemberDeleted deleted member:@"
                        + deletedMember.getScreenName()
                        + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserListSubscription(User subscriber, User listOwner, UserList list) {
                /*System.out.println("onUserListSubscribed subscriber:@"
                        + subscriber.getScreenName()
                        + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserListUnsubscription(User subscriber, User listOwner, UserList list) {
                /*System.out.println("onUserListUnsubscribed subscriber:@"
                        + subscriber.getScreenName()
                        + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserListCreation(User listOwner, UserList list) {
                /*System.out.println("onUserListCreated listOwner:@"
                        + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserListUpdate(User listOwner, UserList list) {
                /*System.out.println("onUserListUpdated listOwner:@"
                        + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserListDeletion(User listOwner, UserList list) {
                /*System.out.println("onUserListDestroyed listOwner:@"
                        + listOwner.getScreenName()
                        + " list:" + list.getName());*/
            }


            public void onUserProfileUpdate(User updatedUser) {
                //System.out.println("onUserProfileUpdated user:@" + updatedUser.getScreenName());
            }

            public void onBlock(User source, User blockedUser) {
                /*System.out.println("onBlock source:@" + source.getScreenName()
                        + " target:@" + blockedUser.getScreenName());*/
            }


            public void onUnblock(User source, User unblockedUser) {
                /*System.out.println("onUnblock source:@" + source.getScreenName()
                        + " target:@" + unblockedUser.getScreenName());*/
            }


            public void onException(Exception ex) {
               /* ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("onException:" + ex.getMessage());*/
            }
        };

        String useIds[] = {"99901654"};




        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.user(useIds);
    }
}
```

errors:

```
UserStreamListener cannot be resolved to a type GetUserStatus.java  /TwitterApi/src   line 18       Java Problem
UserStreamListener cannot be resolved to a type GetUserStatus.java  /TwitterApi/src line 18     Java Problem
TwitterStream cannot be resolved to a type  GetUserStatus.java  /TwitterApi/src line 16         Java Problem
The method getInstance() is undefined for the type TwitterObjectFactory GetUserStatus.java  /TwitterApi/src line 16 Java Problem
The constructor TwitterObjectFactory(Configuration) is undefined    GetUserStatus.java  /TwitterApi/src line 16 Java Problem
```

Comment: Please provide only the **minimal** necessary code for the problem. Nobody will read a huge blob of commented-out code like this.
Spend more time of formatting, to **make it easy to read your question** if you want an answer...

Comment: Are you sure you have the **correct version**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get an stream but your configuration is wrong, maybe your code is from an old version of Twitter4j. This line:

```
 TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterObjectFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

Should be

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

And

```
UserStreamListener listener = new UserStreamListener(){
```

should be

```
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

With the onStallWarning method. You could look this page [Twitter4j - PrintSampleStream.java](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java)

I just try the code with the changes and it works (: